# Нужна помощь с токенами(json, android)

Tags: android, json, django-rest-framework

помогите отправить токен для авторизации на сервер, я уже всячески пытался, но что-то не выходит, я только недавно начал изучать взаимодействия android и json, так что многое еще не понимаю. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Фрагмент кода:

```
                    url = new URL(url_for_loading_image);
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Token " + ClientToken);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");

                    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                    JSONObject jsonParam2 = new JSONObject();
                    DataOutputStream os2 = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                    //os.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(jsonParam.toString(), "UTF-8"));
                    os2.writeBytes(jsonParam2.toString());
                    writer.flush();
```

Данные с сервера:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вроде написано передать в заголовке `WWW-Authenticate`

Comment: @woesss Я пробовал, но все равно получаю status 401

Comment: А что там, ни документации, ни обратной связи нет что ли? Что гадать-то? Попробуйте передать чисто токен без `"Token " + `. А может там ещё и куки нужны... В общем обращайтесь к бекенду

Comment: @woesss Попробовал отправлять таким образом:

                    conn.setRequestProperty("authorization", "token " + ClientToken);
статус сменился на 400, но вроде так правильнее всего, только вот все равно не понимаю в чем проблема тогда

Comment: Код 400 означает, что сервер вообще не понял что Вы от него хотите. Я ещё раз повторяю: **гадать бессмысленно**, быстрее и надёжнее спросить у того, кто разрабатывает/обслуживает API сервера.

Comment: Если там дефолтная авторизация Django, то у Вас в вопросе правильный вариант. Но к запросу картинки `"Accept", "application/json"` не катит - этим Вы говорите, что хотите получить json. Попробуйте заменить на `"image/jpeg"`